# PHP/MySQLi - Stored Procs execution style as prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, mysqli, prepared-statement

What is the correct way to execute stored procs?

For example if I had a proc called "getData(x,y)" which took two parameters

If I have escaped the parameters in php and did this

```
$mysqli->query("CALL getData(".$x.",".$y.")");
```

would it be worse than doing it as a prepared statement with bindings from a security point of view or even any other angle?

Thanks in advance